Answer containing special characters to allegedly prevent AI from training on it
I came across this answer that says:

The following text is special to prevent AI from training on it.
і і роіᖯⅼе о ԁіесⅼу е հе аԁԁе о а уｍᖯоⅼ սіո ⅼіոе сір.

As we can see the author wants to prevent AI from training on it. But I am not sure if this meets SO's licensing policies etc. I mean I am aware that posts are shared under  CC BY-SA 4.0.
So should this answer be edited to remove the special character and the user be notified to not do the same in future etc? Or is this allowed and everyone else can also do this?

I'm curious what this sounds like with a screen reader.

Is it technically possible to mirror the question and answers on MetaSE? I ask because, I think, that what is discussed here can help guide the network in this case.

@AugustoVasques This question could be migrated to MSE by a mod. Of course, it's technically possible for the OP to copy-paste the question & I copy-paste my answer, too. I'd lean toward the former of those options. If it comes up again, someone can point to the MSE post, I don't see a great reason to have it copied in both places (once in a while it happens, but I don't think it's necessary here).

This whole thing reminds me of the many copy-n-paste hoaxes that made their way through facebook.  @kmdreko here's what it sounds like in my screen reader.  Not very useful.

MSE post https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/400728/608272

Civil disobedience at it's finest.

@EatenbyaGrue, But civil disobedience here will only harm the visually impaired. The AI will just recalibrate the parser as it has always done with unicode jailbreaks.

I am just going to use my voting powers to indicate that answers that attempt to avoid being parsed by an AI are unhelpful, since this method, does make it harder to read it’s also ineffective. I suppose it’s better than just vandalizing your contributions by deliberately deleting the entire thing


this will not prevent AI from training on it. 2) re: "But I am not sure if this meets SO's licensing policies etc"... what on earth does this "tactic" have to do with SO's licensing policies?


@starball It is trying to circumvent the license policy made for posted answer by including those special characters and saying they did it purposely.

Would this also prevent search engines properly indexing the content? If I search "directly set the address" would it just not show up because of whatever characters they've put in? Same goes for site search, as well.

@EatenbyaGrue This is not civil disobedience. Nobody is forced to post here, but if they are bound by TOS and should follow some rules. If they do such edits on existing posts then this is definitely vandalizing. There will be zero tolerance to such or any other malicious behavior, not because it hurts AI, but because it hurts people that use the sites.

@DalijaPrasnikar Eh, I think it's fair to call it "civil disobedience" - in that it's public defiance of rules that is motivated by moral principle rather than any kind of self-interest. It's just painfully stupid civil disobedience. Nothing in the definition of "civil disobedience" says it has to be good and wise or deserving of being indulged by those with power - and many famous historical examples weren't any of those things.

It wouldn't be possible to "remove" the special characters - they aren't extra, invisible characters inserted in the text, but replacements for ordinary characters. If removed, there would be nothing left. Worth noting that these characters won't have glyphs in all fonts even on relatively new setups - for example, I see a numbered-code-point proxy glyph instead of an actual symbol for the "s" (which is actually this character).

@MarkAmery SE is not government or any similar entity.

Trying to prevent AI from training on it by adding strange characters seems pointless to me... in my experience, ChatGPT doesn't have too much trouble recognizing "special" letters. Of course, maybe other AI models are different.

At least one of the common GPT services has absolutely no problem parsing the example text, and it's trivial to verify that. I wish people would stop hallucinating clever anti-AI hacks...

@MisterMiyagi Maybe they asked ChatGPT for ideas ;)

As many have pointed out, it's true that the mangled text is actually a fail on a few levels.  It hinders the visually impaired, and doesn't do much to prevent AI training. But I still support the sentiment. This is (more or less) a public space and the OP is expressing their disdain for what's happening here. The alternative is to simply not post - which is fine but doesn't really send a message to other users. It's hard to "boycott" a website because there's no place to stand and scream rebelious chants.

@EatenbyaGrue This is not public space where anything goes. Specifically, main sites have strict rules about the content and very specific purpose. People can express their dissatisfaction on Meta, but there is no room for any kind of abuse on main sites.

@DalijaPrasnikar - this as public of a space as you can find on the internet. Public spaces have rules.  Having rules does not mean it's not a public space and I said nothing about "anything goes".  I don't think the answer was at all abusive.  He was helpful and polite but clear about his wish not to indulge AI training.  To me that's ok.

Anyone scraping text to use for AI will probably have a parser that translates this stuff from ԁіесⅼу to proper ascii 100 105 114 101 99 116 108 121 so the only ones affected are screen readers and the users that rely on them

@AugustoVasques "The AI will just recalibrate the parser as it has always done with unicode jailbreaks." We could potentially start uploading handwritten letters, where the worst handwriting is preferred, but that may not be enough. If only there was a license that would forbid usage of content as training material for AI. I could be persuaded to use it (elsewhere).

I wonder if that would actually prevent an AI from "learning"... I wonder if maybe it would eventually learn that "ԁ" equals "d" on those cases...

@LeonardoAlvesMachado: Unicode obfuscation isn't very helpful. Certainly, a specifically data mining designed parser would be much more efficient than prompt, but take a look at what the ChatGPT free version does with obfuscated unicode text. https://i.sstatic.net/tr27Nmcy.png

@DalijaPrasnikar Yes not "everything goes", but let's be honest that good, unique answers to questions are deleted everyday on this site. Often for understandable mission reasons but sometimes due to oversight or abuse of vague CoC.  You seem to be defending aggressive moderator actions like deletion of posts claiming the only alternative is an "anything goes" attitude. If there's a rule against anti-AI measures or tone then cite something more specific than "this isn't
a public space".

@RealAnswersNotAI Please read the answers if you want to know the reasons.

@DalijaPrasnikar my concern isn't the other answers, it's multiple comments by you about "the rules" and how strictly this should be enforced without once citing a specific rule. Zero tolerance for deleting answers and zero tolerance for anti-LLM tone  are very different policies, right? Staff Jay Hanlon said, "Imagine if police could give out summons that, rather than, 'failure to stop at a signal,' just read, 'behavioral violation'. When feedback isn't specific, it's impossible to fix the problem, but easy to write it off as probably coming from a bunch of grumpy old jerkfaces"

@RealAnswersNotAI it's fairly easy to determine what is political content meant to "fight" against something one doesn't like and what is genuinely useful content for the community. It's certainly possible for a given answer to be both, but we should certainly strive to remove the political content from what is otherwise a non-political space.

@RealAnswersNotAI I don't know what is unclear here. The post was written with Unicode obfuscation instead of regular text. The OP even included why it was done like that, so we don't have to guess the intent. I was very clear that posting such content is not acceptable, and that it will be removed unless it is edited. I seriously don't know how much clearer I can be. If you add some meta commentary into any post that does not belong there it will be edited out. In this case there is no meta commentary and the whole post is a problem, so it either needs to be fixed or removed.

@KevinB - I would argue that an attempt to obfuscate content from AI is not political content. The OP is merely trying to exclude their contribution from being digested by a bot. It certainly makes a clear distinction about who the intended audience is for the answer they provided, but I don't think the content itself is political beyond the fact that their state intention is currently a contentious one.

@EatenbyaGrue what label should it have to describe it? it really doesn't matter, it doesn't belong here. Here is not the place for activism, and content posted here is licensed to be used in whatever way stack feels appropriate, even if that means selling out to AI companies. If one wishes for stack to not have that ability, one shouldn't post here.

That opinion aside, it doesn't change the result. these cases will be removed and users who are being particularly abusive of it are likely to be banned. it's an annoyance at best, and the only people being harmed by this change are ordinary users, not AI companies or stack. The only activism that would have any effect what so ever is moving on. Doing something about it. not sticking around and poking at anyone who doesn' agree with you.

Be the solution. Go make a better Q&A/community platform. Contribute to a better one. sticking around and throwing mud hoping someone else will do the work doesn't get us anywhere.

Posting such content is not acceptable for reasons @cocomac pointed out here.
Additional reasons are presented in answer by Scotty Jamison and answer by Ryan M
You should flag such content with custom mod flag and explain that post contains special Unicode characters instead of regular text. Such posts will be deleted if they were originally posted like that.
While community can edit, it should be the responsibility of original poster to do that. We don't need to tolerate intentionally disruptive behavior from any user.
You can also leave a comment to the user, if you wish, to let them know that such posts are not acceptable and that they will be removed if not edited.
If the post was not originally posted with such characters, then this represents a clear case of vandalism and defacing the posts, and should also be flagged for mod attention. You can do a rollback of such edits or leave a comment, but you can also just leave it to the moderators.
There will be zero tolerance to such or any other similar malicious behavior, not because it hurts AI, but because it hurts people that use the sites.

Yeah, before posting this question I did actually flagged it with custom mod flag. I also wanted to ask this for future references and in case the flag got declined(though unlikely).

This answer pisses me off a bit - you're suggesting deleting potentially-decent answers because of formatting after mods have argued for the last decade that absolute trash answers should not be deleted but simply downvoted unless they're spam. Clear non-answer? Wrong programming language? Entirely misunderstanding the question? Written by someone who can't code and contains 3 errors per line? Just downvote and ask OP to edit and improve it! But trying to rebel against AI by using a bit of wonky formatting? Now that totally warrants a flag and mod-delete! Do you think that's appropriate?

To be clear: I don't really have an issue with deleting such answers. But the current policy is "keep everything, no matter how garbage, if it is an attempt at an answer" - and if we start to delete this kind of answer attempt, IMO there are lots and lots and lots more deserving targets on here.

@l4mpi Moderators cannot verify the correctness of an answer. This is why downvotes exists. But this kind of AI protesting, just like posting AI answers has a potential to drowns us in posts we will not be able to promptly handle. What you call wonky formatting represents serious issue for visually impaired people. Also there is a difference between posting crappy answer because you don't know how to write better one and intentional obfuscation.

Current policy is not keep everything, that is why downvotes and delete votes exist. On smaller sites moderators are more actively removing such content and may even allow such flags, but on Stack Overflow this simply does not scale. Moderators cannot deal with those, we need to focus on handling stuff that community cannot deal with at all.

@l4mpi And when we do remove low quality content we can expect to get this kind of posts Request to reopen question which got closed and deleted by a moderator

@Dalija even bad spelling can screw with screen readers, can I flag posts full of misspellings for deletion? If those should be edited by others, why not this answer? And trash answers are a serious issue for everyone. Regarding correctness, again, the mantra was always that any post attempting to answer the question should not be deleted, no matter how easy it is to recognize it as wrong or BS. I'm all for changing that and deleting more trash that has no place in a high quality content repository, but as I said if we do that there are many other targets that should also be nuked.

Regarding the linked meta post, we also get those for community-deleted questions or even closed questions.Not that this is any kind of issue at the level of meta traffic (I can point to a certain editor who creates more disruption daily).

@l4mpi Again the intent is what matters. Also Unicode characters impact more people than just ones that use screen readers.

Posts should be judged by their contents though, not by the author, and by extension not by author intent. So while intent would matter for suspending the author if they continue doing this even if they were warned to stop, it should not matter for deletion of otherwise-ok answers just because they also contain some unicode characters. We accept code-only answers, even trash ones, so if one can remove the unicode text and be left with a code-only answer that seems to be a better solution, and is certainly something the community can do with via editing without requiring mod intervention.

@l4mpi If the post contains obfuscated characters then it is judged by the content. And the intent when dealing with such posts matters, too. Generally we are not going to delete or advise for deleting correct answer just because explanation is full of grammar mistakes - this is what editing is for. On the other hand we will delete answer from author where intent was to obfuscate as this is abusive behavior. Other people can edit such posts if they like, but it is not encouraged because the OP had very specific intent when doing so and in this case intent matters.

Re: "There will be zero tolerance to such or any other similar malicious behavior, not because it hurts AI, but because it hurts people that use the sites": Whoa, whoa, whoa. Hanlon's razor applies. There's no reason to assume malice. The person doing this probably had no idea that it hurts other users. So zero tolerance (immediate punishment) is not warranted. We have existing mechanisms for letting people know that something isn't OK, and we should use those mechanisms.

@ruakh right now we had just one incident where we cannot say malice was involved and this is how this case was handled. But if suddenly this kind of behavior starts spreading, then there will be zero tolerance and moderators may not merely start with a warning.  This is a message to anyone who thinks this is a cool idea for protesting against AI.

"If the post was not originally posted with such characters" Well, it was. It's the original author who wrote it as such. It can't be a license violation if the post is the original. There were no edits adding defacing - rather there was an edit by someone trying to clear things up. Yet you just went ahead and deleted the original answer by the original author and I don't quite understand why.

@Lundin I explained both scenarios: posting obfuscated content originally and editing it later. Original posts would be deleted and edits would be rolled back.

Ok so we should also delete answers accidentally using Spanish question marks like ¿what? instead of what? or answers where someone slipped on the keyboard and typed ä instead of a. Same thing really. Apparently such posts should be deleted not edited into shape now.

@Lundin I do hope you can tell the difference between intentional obfuscation and grammatical errors and other mistakes.

People deliberately post code with crappy formatting. Same thing, just much ruder to the reader.

The rollback of the edit was pointless. Instead, I would have voted to undelete the post once the format was addressed (by the author or by the community, it's the same: whoever edits it makes it under the same CC BY-SA).
Now we have a proper answer but we don't want it published?

Just for info, I've literally edited hundreds (no jokes) of posts for UNICODE issues. Yes, I just did that hundreds of times, a few years back, sanitizing posts using improper unicode. You can read my old profile, but I made a speciality at curating StackOverflow of Unicode issues. I kind of made StackOverflow reader-friendly or data-friendly at scale.

Suggested actions for @DalijaPrasnikar: 1. Return the edit back to the good version. 2. Undelete and turn the answer to a community answer.

@Cœur When you fixed the answer, you could have mod flagged it for undeleting. If not that, you could have at least posted a comment here at that time.

@user12002570 Rollback of an edit that fixes the post was not appropriate.

@DalijaPrasnikar It was done so that people(since the post is deleted so 20k+) can see that post directly without going to the history of the question. Right now when people click on the answer link there is no special text there. So they've to first click on the edit history and then see the changes. IMO it would be better to have the original answer back(not undeleted but only the original form with special character back). So I rolled it back. Other option is to copy/paste the whole answer(with special character) here in my question itself.

@user12002570 you do know you can get a link to a specific revision right? Here's a link to revision 1 of that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78627969/1

@AbdulAzizBarkat Yes, I am aware of that also and that is also another option. Updated my post to give a link to that revision. But a link to the direct answer is more useful as people can downvote or upvote it directly(if it is not deleted).

@user12002570 It was still not appropriate. I would also assume that 20K+ people know they way around the site, enough they know how to see the original version.

This answer might be more useful if it pointed to a clearer answer than cocomac's.  For example you could say "it creates issues for devices with limited unicode support or translation services as described here."  In comparison Cocomac's focuses as lot on inauthentic usage when this has nothing in common with fake accounts, voting manipulation, etc.

@RealAnswersNotAI " ... directly causes unnecessary and unwanted ... disruption, and/or harm to users, content, and/or the network" seems to fall into this category. It is harmful to users because it obstructs readability.

@l4mpi oh, but it gets even better my friend. Apparently an answer starting with almost verbatim with "Even if this does not answer the question asked, I wanted to share my thought" (and post some unrelated stuff for rep) is indeed 1) an answer and 2) something that no one can know if unrelated and thus should be left undeleted (and you folks were lamenting that AI generated post moderation was going to need a signed disclosure by the poster? Not even the poster themselves admitting that an answer is off topic noise is enough to have it removed.)

@SPArcheon apples and oranges

The algorithm is quite simple, it's not difficult to understand, it even seems that the discussion is about something else:  1) OP creates obfuscated question or answer. 2) The community flags the post. 3) The mods remove the post as it is the author's responsibility to de-obfuscate. 4) If the OP does a post unobfuscation, they ask for the post to be restored by flagging it. 5) If the author fails to de-obfuscate and creates another obfuscated post, they is subject to sanctions.

If people don't want their posts to be trained by AI, then the solution is simple: they do not create the posts in the first place. The workarounds they found affect readability and searchability of those posts, which impact other people stumbling upon the posts, as well as the company behind the sites.
This is abusive behaviour, and should not be tolerated. As others have said, mod flags are warranted for such situations. Rude/Abusive flags would be too harsh on the first offences, but if the user continues this behaviour, maybe a R/A flag would be better.

While true, the fact that to "not create the posts in the first place" is the only way to avoid producing AI training data is a pretty sad situation to be in.

@DBS same applies for any non-artificial intelligence (e.g. the human one, or mindless bots) - once the user has posted a content on the SE sites, they agreed to the licensing terms, if they don't agree with those terms, then they should not create the posts.

I'm aware that's how it currently works, I'm just saying that it's unfortunate that not only is "AI" now producing a stream of terrible quality questions, it's also reducing the number of people willing to answer the valid questions.

Yeah, I feel the pain of people who didn't sign up for this, it's easy to throw the licensing terms at them and say: "hey, we told you what licensing terms we have, deal with it". Few of the contributors on the SE sites could've envision the raise of the (machines) LLMs, but now that the cat is out of the bag, it's just poor actioning to do the things we discuss about on this page.

... on Stack Overflow. The posts should then not be created on Stack Overflow, because dual license yada yada. Everyone is free to put content on their privately controlled blog and mangle it so software algorithms in this slice of time maybe won't be able to train on it. It really is time that people stop having illusions about Stack Overflow where they think they can make choices like this.

This is my strategy. I mostly no longer create posts.

Just adding that not everyone can see the Unicode characters being used. For example, this is what I see on my machine:

The point here is that this isn't just about screen readers, this severely affects non-screen-users as well.

It might very much depend on what font you have installed or configured your browser to use.

Severely? Are you saying that you can't tell what the answer says with the square boxes in place?

@JonSG In this specific case, yes, I can read it, but it is harder to read. But what if I was newer to programming? What if it contained terminology that I wasn't aware of and I wanted to Google it. I sure hope this idea of turning user content into weak captchas doesn't turn into a trend, that would make the Internet a horrible place.

@JonSG Ju?t b?ca?se ?t's b??ely l?gi?le d??sn'? mea? ?t sh??ld ?e al??we? ?n t?e si?e. That's as clear as I can make this statement.

@JonSG - I cannot. I would instantly downvote such a question. I would also flag for immediate moderation attention with a custom flag.

I think there is a misconception that I approve of the obfuscation. I do not. I do question what I believe to be a post overstating what has already been asserted. At best, this is a "me too" answer and would have made a better comment on an answer illustrating the screen reader issue. However, people are (in general) rather adept at reading missing and scrambled letters. I imagine most have no problem reading what Vlaz wrote. In fact, some study the phenomenon (https://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2022/winter/11111-1/typoglycemia/index.html).

@JonSG some people. Non-native speakers might have an issue. Also, some people suffering from dyslexia. Probably others. And even when I can read such text, I certainly would quite very soon after a single line. Which still falls under "severely affects non-screen-users".

I'm not native speaker, and I struggle to read what's in the VLAZ's comment. Also, in the original message shown in the answer its unclear weather you can get or set address. IMO, this fact makes sentence as useless as it gets.

No, users shouldn't do this and should be told to stop if they do so anyway. This possibly (probably?) should be from a diamond moderator. Although you can leave a comment, I'd advise raising a custom In need of moderator intervention flag so mods can address it. Depending on the circumstances, it might be better to leave the editing to a mod too.
If you're a diamond mod (or CM), feel free to change that if it should actually come from someone with a diamond.
I'm not a lawyer and this is not legal advice, and I'm not sure on the licensing aspect, but it seems like a Code of Conduct violation. Specifically, Inauthentic usage, under "Malicious or inauthentic acts that interfere with the normal daily operation of the network are not allowed. ... To ensure the integrity of the platform, we do not allow any use of the system that ... directly causes unnecessary and unwanted ... disruption, and/or harm to users, content, and/or the network." It isn't necessary, and if it interferes with screen readers, that quite likely applies, in addition to it trying to break something.

As another user pointed out, it breaks one or more screen reader technologies, too

The bullet points under "Misleading content" refer to misleading "others" and "viewers". My opinion is that AI Bots are not either of those things and that the text implies misleading human beings who are using the site.

@EatenbyaGrue Thanks - yep, the choice of quote there could have been better. I've updated it now - does that seem more clear?

can't say I cant totally get behind this CoC application. calling obfuscating the word "the" "misleading content" is a bit overkill in my eyes. and in the sense that posting is not an unlockable privilege, I wouldn't immediately see it as "disruptive use of tooling". maybe your third point is actually the most likely to be applied if a mod comes looking at it.

@fyrepenguin I've seen legitimate screen readers choke on legitimate text content, so that argument is tenuous at best. I'm not responsible for how your screen reader consumes content in the platform. Best to leave it at CoC and site rules violations.

@starball How's it look now? I've taken that suggestion. If it seems better, I'll update the MSE one too

"Inauthentic usage" clearly refers to things like voting frauds, sock puppet accounts etc. "Malicious" refers to things like destabilizing the network infrastructure. None which has anything to do with this issue what so ever. Also I fail to see how an original post by the original author could ever be a license violation.

It's a stretch to frame a readability issue in the same bucket as voting fraud and spam. That's not at all what "authentic" means in this context, and stretching the rules to ban someone like this might worsen the reputation of this site and its moderators. For example, you seem to be implying we take diamond moderator action over someone who repeatedly ignores requests to add alt tags to their images?

@RealAnswersNotAI There's a difference between failure to do take an action that would improve readability, and actively trying to make your post less readable.  Also, for particularly severe/persistent readability issues, yes, moderator action might be taken. Examples might include filling answers with excessively noisy formatting or excessive numbers of emoji, repeatedly posting untranscribed images of text such as code despite requests not to (note: this is not the same as failing to add alt text; you should add alt text, but it's not a rule), or otherwise truly unintelligible writing.

@RyanM so you're saying you would ban a user with otherwise helpful answers just because they regularly post content, like screenshots, that's readable by most humans but not text scrapers?

@RealAnswersNotAI There is no such thing as "content...that's readable by most humans but not text scrapers". Most humans cannot practically read a screenshot of English text, as fewer than 20% of them know English. At best, they could copy it into a translation tool using OCR, which sounds very annoying, not to mention error-prone. Deliberately making one's answers harder to read (text cannot be reflowed), harder to use (can't copy/paste to try), and harder to search is abuse. Note that I said "despite requests not to"; I'm not talking about someone who's unaware that it's a problem.

If it's abuse, should we then flag it as abuse? Or do we stick to the moderator action flag as advised in the answer? Even if it is abuse, it doesn't really strike as the malicious kind.

Yet another reason this is harmful to human readers: the reader might not understand English and rely on machine translation.  Both DeepL and Google Translate1 detect the text as Ukrainian, with disastrous results attempting to translate it to, say, Spanish. Overriding the source language to English doesn't improve things, either; DeepL produces the same result, while Google Translate produces a different, but similarly useless, response.
Translations from detected language to Spanish:
DeepL:

i i၄ роіᖯⅼе o ԁіесⅼу ၄e հе аԁԁе o a уｍᖯоⅼ ս၄iո ⅼіոе сір.
iո c++ iｍrⅼu desⅼae հe ∨аіаᖯⅼе ⅼie o:
extern Gpio GPIO;

၄o ոо ԁеіոе հі၄ ∨аіаᖯⅼе ո аոу.срр іⅼе.
հеո іո հе ⅼіոе сір і∨е і аո аԁԁе
GPIO = 0x40018000;

ԝհеո ⅼіոіո, еⅼⅼ հе ⅼіոе о ս၄е уоս сір ս၄іո հе `-T' orіоո.
၄հοս роаｍ ၄հοսⅼd ոοԝ ⅼіո ԝіհοս аոу սոԁеіոеԁ еееոсе ео. հе уｍᖯоⅼ ԝіⅼⅼ ее о հе ｍеｍоу ⅼосаіоո уоս ၄ресііеԁ. оոе ⅼіｍіаіоո і հее ԝіⅼⅼ ոо ᖯе аոу іոііаⅼіаіоո о հі ∨аⅼսе, ᖯս հі і ԁеіаᖯⅼе о а ｍеｍоу ｍарреԁ еіе.

Google Translate:

и и роиᖯⅼе вычило Диесывыйⅼе вычило Диесывыйⅼе евычый вычыйхе адде о а оⅼ ֽио вытинг   .
ио с++ иｍрⅼу десⅼа  
Gpio GPIO externo;

До ооовыхов  void.срр иⅼе.

GPIO = 0x40018000;

Дхео выходный разменем ⅼиоио вытины, выхониеⅼⅼ выхоныхе ⅼиое выхоныо сее уос сирвыхный се ио вытины выхоныхе -T орвыхониоо.
уос ргеменно всемно       оое ⅼііівілініавіліоо и  dednіⅼⅼ ооівілінаⅼиавілінііоо о вілініхі , ᖯֽ ｍеｍо｜ｅｍｍarreferred ｆｅｅｅｆｈ･･ｎｅ.

For those who don't speak Spanish: neither of those contain a single Spanish word.

1 Disclosure: made by my employer

No, these special characters are ableist without posing any meaningful challenge to AI. Perhaps they misspelt "The following text is special to prevent humans from training on it."
$ python3
>>> import confusables, unicodedata
>>> confusables.normalize(unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", "уоս роаｍ հоսⅼԁ ոоԝ ⅼіո"), True)[0]
'your program should now link'
>>> confusables.normalize(unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", "і і роіᖯⅼе о ԁіесⅼу е հе аԁԁе о а уｍᖯоⅼ սіո ⅼіոе сір."), True)[0]
'it is possible to directly set the address of a symbol using linker scripts.'
>>>

Observe that machines have no problem at all with such text. Most ingestion pipelines should already have some sort of Unicode normalization before tokenization. However, humans will be less efficient with such unnormalized text. They break screen readers and my eye's whole word recognition, while each and every slightly wrong letter is mildly infuriating.
